# Android Equalizer - How to use ACTION_OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION?

Tags: android, equalizer, audioeffect

I want to apply equalizer changes to all apps. However, the use of 0 as a global session id was deprecated, you have to use:

```
        mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, mPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
```

instead of        `mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, 0);`

According to [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html#ACTION_OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION), you can use ACTION_OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION to receive the id of a playing audio session:

> Intent to signal to the effect control application or service that a new audio session is opened and requires audio effects to be applied.

**However, how are you supposed to use it?** I tried adding the constant in the manifest, but it didn't work:

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.AudioSessionReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

(when I play an audio file, or a music video, the receiver isn't called)

If this is not the way to apply audio (equalizer) settings to other apps, what is?

**Update**: I simply had issues with the Logcat, now it works, but only with Spotify and not other apps.

Comment: Hi, i had the same issue. I maybe wrong, but i think that depends on the app's media player sending the event (android.media.action.OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION). I tested with dezzer and my receiver was called only when i enabled the equalizer active option on the settings.

Comment: I have tried it and it works to me with Play Music app. I would like to use it with Google Meet, but I don't find how to make it work...